# What problem is this application of simulated annealing trying to solve?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, monte-carlo, physics, simulated-annealing

I was reading about simulated annealing on its Wikipedia page, and was drawn to a particular example illustrating the annealing schedule. Below is the picture and its description:

[image]

> Example illustrating the effect of cooling schedule on the performance of simulated annealing. The problem is to rearrange the pixels of an image so as to minimize a certain potential energy function, which causes similar colours to attract at short range and repel at a slightly larger distance. The elementary moves swap two adjacent pixels. These images were obtained with a fast cooling schedule (left) and a slow cooling schedule (right), producing results similar to amorphous and crystalline solids, respectively.

I am drawn to this particular problem – that of rearranging pixels using this algorithm – for its connections to crystal formation, but I am finding it impossible to find a starting point to learn more about it on the internet. I know this is an unconventional question but I would like to know what this particular problem is called or the greater context it belongs in.

Comment: Wikipedia provides no pointers. All we can do is guess.

Comment: I know, it's odd that this wasn't accompanied by a reference. I was hoping someone on stackexchange might however have encountered this particular problem.